# Error running grails run-war after half a day

Tags: grails, war

I have a 2.1.1 grails app which I am running using grails run-war. It works well, and runs for quite some time, but stops after something between 12 and 24 hours. I am never observing the app when it fails. It always just says "bad"

```
$ grails run-war 
| Done creating WAR target/web-0.1.war
| Running Grails application
Tomcat Server running WAR (output written to: target/tomcat-out.txt)
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8090/web
bad
$
```

2 of the last 3 failures has produced this in the output file:

```
2012-10-10 10:22:46,684 [localhost-startStop-2] ERROR loader.WebappClassLoader  - The web application [/web] appears to have started a thread named [Poller SunPKCS11-Darwin] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2012-10-10 10:22:46,694 [localhost-startStop-2] ERROR loader.WebappClassLoader  - The web application [/web] appears to have started a thread named [MongoCleaner1292971653] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

However most of the time, there is nothing in the log file.

This happens even if nobody has used the webapp, ie its been idle. The plugins in use are:

```
    runtime ":mongodb:1.0.0.GA"
    runtime ":jquery:1.7.2"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.15"
    runtime ":resources:1.2-RC1"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
```

WHen using grails 2.0.4, this same app ran for weeks without failing. The only change is the upgrade to grails 2.1.1

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Edit:
Including the DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in each Model,

```
class Album {
static mapWith = "mongo"
```

I do this to ensure I use Mongo as each time I upgrade grails, it automatically re-installs the hibernate plugin even though I keep uninstalling it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include your datasource config?

Comment: Its unmodified - I'm using mongo to write to the DB, when used...